# Check user changed his password recently or not in specific period

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working on Oracle SQL. What I am trying to do is:

1. Query a record with ID
2. If the record does not exists use user input value
3. If the record exists, compare `last_login_date` column and user input value (I put `to_date('20160401', 'yyyymmdd')` then pick recent one)
4. Add `not_change_day` to result of `3`, then compare the value with `sysdate`
5. If `4` is bigger then `sysdate` then returns `true` else `false`

```
select 
    case when (a.ncd + a.lld > sysdate) then 'true' 
    else 'false' end as result
from
(
    select 
        nvl(not_change_day, 90) as ncd,
        case 
            when last_login_date is null then to_date('20160401','yyyymmdd')
            when last_login_date > to_date('20160401','yyyymmdd') then last_login_date
        END as lld
    from 
        FT_PWD_CHANGE
    where 
        id='some_id'
) a
```

RESULT

```
result
------
false
```

However, I believe there are too many `case when` statements and sub-queries. Would you suggest a more efficient way?

Comment: Please tell us what you are _really_ trying to do, and also make that the title of your question. (It should probably be something about recent password changes.)

Comment: @200_success Is it ok for now? I made title more specific but feels like it is too specific topic.

Comment: I've removed the remark about "not working", as that would make your question off-topic for Code Review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query doesn't returns a result when there's no `id` matching `'some_id'`.

Well, there's a trick to force a row, use an aggregate function.

I think this is your logic rewritten to a single CASE (of course COALESCE is just a shortcut for a CASE :-)

```
SELECT COALESCE(MIN(CASE WHEN Greatest(COALESCE(last_login_date, to_date('20160401','yyyymmdd'))
                                      ,to_date('20160401','yyyymmdd')
                             + COALESCE(not_change_day, 90) > sysdate 
                         THEN 'true'
                     END)
                    ,'false')
FROM FT_PWD_CHANGE
WHERE id='foo'
```

Btw, for a hard-coded date I would prefer `DATE '2016-04-01'` over `to_date('20160401','yyyymmdd')`, it's shorter and Standard SQL.